# Force placement of currently unplaced figures before a certain block of text

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column

A paper I am writing is quite figure-heavy, and one of my sections has more figures than text.  Unfortunately, because of this, the figures get spread out through the rest of my paper and even end up on several pages after the end of my text.  I would like to avoid this behavior by making sure the figures all get placed before a certain spot in my paper, towards the end (like my references section).  Is there a command that forces LaTeX to place all the figures not yet placed by a certain spot in the text at that spot in the text?

I wish to emphasize that it is not my desire to use the `[H]` specifier.  I am just fine with LaTeX positioning my figures for me, I just want them to all be placed before a certain spot in my paper.

Also please note that `\newpage` and `\clearpage` are not options for me.  I don't want to force a page break; I would like the subsequent text to follow the figures naturally without a page break between the figures and the following text.  I basically want the float-placing behavior of `\newpage` without actually making a new page.

Here is a minimum working example to try and explain what I am talking about.  Currently, this code places all the text on the first page interspersed with all the figures, and the two-column wide figure* gets placed on the second page.  What I was is the text of the first section to appear on the first page with as many figures as possible (the normal LaTeX thing to do), and then the second page to get all the leftover figures (the larger figure* in this case) and for the second section's text to appear *after* that figure and *not as a new page*, but on the same page as that figure.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %used to generate filler text

 \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Section with figures}
\lipsum[66]

\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure*}
Some more text.
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}
Some more text yet again.
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}
And, yet again, more text.
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}

\section{After figures}
I want this text to appear {\bf after} all the figures above, but not
simply on a fresh page after the last figure.  I would like it to
start running after the last figure.  For instance, if the last figure
takes a page, I would like this text to continue right after it
such that the figure is on the top half and this text is on the bottom
half of the page.

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a dupe: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764) And if that's not, then this is: [`\clearpage` without page break?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88657/5764)

Comment: @Werner not  either if those that answers the question really

Comment: I think this may do what you want (I'd be interested to know if it doesn't..) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246155/how-to-place-floats-between-paragraphs/246315#246315

Comment: `\FloatBarrier` of package `placeins` helps?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Yes, that's covered in [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek `\FloatBarrier`, as pointed out by David Carlisle, issues a `\clearpage`, which I *don't* want.

Comment: @Werner, I was not able to find the answer to my question in either of your links.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, `\flushhere` did not work.  I ended up with several blank pages between two sets of figures and many of my figures ended up past the point I wanted them to.  Also, at least one of my figures didn't even show up in the final PDF (one that was supposed to appear after the `\flushhere` command).

Comment: @Werner, `\afterpage{\clearpage}` is close (probably the closest so far) but still not quite what I am looking for.  I think it will work though.

Comment: @Joshua: If you consider your post not to be a duplicate, then describe why/how it differs. Ideally in such cases, present the community with a minimal example that replicates your problem. Honestly, it'll go a long way to solving your issue. Remove all the "personal" information and just give us something to work with (using [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) and images from [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe)) that highlights the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, if there's anything you would suggest adding to my question to make it clearer what I am asking (you seem to understand best so far) please let me know/add it.

Comment: @Joshua: Hmmm, you didn't say that you were using `twocolumn`... floats in columns are, tricky and not-float-worthy, and intermixing it with double-column `figure*` style floats is cause for concern (when thinking about float numbering).

Comment: @Werner, I forgot I was using `twocolumn` until just now.  Don't worry about float numbering, this is not a question about float numbering.  My original question stands whether I'm using one or two columns.  I basically want the float-placing behavior of `\newpage` without actually making a new page.

Comment: @Joshua: Sure. I'm pretty sure things can be done to suit your needs, however hackish it may end up being. Float numbering may re-surface...

Comment: @Joshua twocolumn makes the problem a lot harder

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I don't understand how one or two columns would make the problem different.

Comment: two column floats are much harder to implement and are much more constrained than single column, they always go to the _next_ page never the page with their source, they do not support bottom `b` or here `h` float position.

Comment: @Joshua Please consider removing comments. (I removed a few which became obsolete) because it's not a chat but comments add information (temporarily). Feel free to go to the TeX.SE chat to discuss further.

Answer (score 3):

You mention [no concern about float numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252268/force-placement-of-currently-unplaced-figures-before-a-certain-block-of-text?noredirect=1#comment602250_252268), so my suggestion would be to forego any kind of floating for the single-column `figure`s. For this, use the `[H]` float specifier:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %used to generate filler text

\usepackage{afterpage,float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Section with figures}
\lipsum[66]

\begin{figure*}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure*}

Some more text.

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}

Some more text yet again.

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}

And, yet again, more text.

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\section{After figures}
I want this text to appear \textbf{after} all the figures above, but not
simply on a fresh page after the last figure.  I would like it to
start running after the last figure.  For instance, if the last figure
takes a page, I would like this text to continue right after it
such that the figure is on the top half and this text is on the bottom
half of the page.

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

The two-column `figure*` is placed after a `\newpage`. However, you can play around with the placement of this float without your actual document text (again, ignoring float numbering).

Answer (score 2):

As the two column float has to span the top of the following page, and (in latex 2015 release, or with `fixltx2e` with older format) all floats are kept in order, and so the single column floats have to come after that, I do not see how you can avoid a lot of white space after the first section, however you can do

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %used to generate filler text

 \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure*}

\section{Section with figures}
\lipsum[66]
Some more text.
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}
Some more text yet again.
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}
And, yet again, more text.
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
\end{figure}

\newpage\mbox{}\newpage

\section{After figures}
I want this text to appear \textbf{after} all the figures above, but not
simply on a fresh page after the last figure.  I would like it to
start running after the last figure.  For instance, if the last figure
takes a page, I would like this text to continue right after it
such that the figure is on the top half and this text is on the bottom
half of the page.

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```