# Allow free floats but not before section title or inside sections

Tags: floats, positioning

I have many figures with large captions. Because of this it is confusing if these figures are inserted in the middle of a paragraph. Also because of LaTeX strong preferences to place floats at the top of the page, they often end up before the section title.

I'm perfectly fine with LaTeX placing my floats where they fit nicely, but it hould still adhere some rules.

1) I want a new page before a new section starts. I also want all floats from the previous sections to be paced before this new page. I've already solved this with the `\clearpage` command. Namely:

```
cstyle={\ttfamily},literate={↓}{$\downarrow{}$}{1}}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\clearpage\oldsection} % add a new page before every section.
```

2) It's allowed for sections and paragraphs to be split over multiple pages, but floats should not be placed on top of the page if a paragraph was split. Special float pages should also not be inserted on pages where the previous paragraph continues on the next page.

3) Floats do not have to be mandatory placed on the top or bottom of the page, they can freely go anywhere between paragraphs.

So far the only solutions i've found is to micromanage all my floats by using `[!htb]`.

Comment: try this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246155/how-to-place-floats-between-paragraphs/246315#246315

Comment: Also, you might increase \bottomfraction, since the default (0.3) is relatively small.