# using \flushhere for table/figure position

Tags: floats, packages, positioning

I am creating a new question using `\flushere` that get the idea from [\flushhere idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246155/how-to-place-floats-between-paragraphs/246315?noredirect=1#comment1282389_246315)

I found 2 problems:
1. It seemed the figure/table are placed correctly without:
a) splitting the paragraph
b) leaving a large blank space.

2. Did I used the `\flushere` correctly?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

 \usepackage{showframe}
 \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
 \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{makecell,siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{parskip} % <================================================
\usepackage{caption} % <================================================
\setcounter{totalnumber}{30}% lots of here floats

\makeatletter
\def\flushhere{\par{%
 \let\s@deferlist\@deferlist
 \let\@currbox\relax
\@next\@currbox\@deferlist{%
  \ifodd\count\@currbox
\typeout{Trying \meaning\@currbox (\number\@currbox/\the\count\@currbox),
        adding to \meaning\@currlist}%
    \@cons\@currlist\@currbox
\typeout{added: to \meaning\@currlist}%
\typeout{deferlist was \s@deferlist, now \@deferlist}%
\let\s@@deferlist\@deferlist\@empty
\global\let\@deferlist\@empty
    \@floatpenalty -\@Miii
      \penalty -\@Miv
      \@tempdima\prevdepth
      \vbox{}%
      \prevdepth\@tempdima
      \penalty\@floatpenalty
       \@@par
   \ifx\@deferlist\@empty
\typeout{float placed here}%
\global\let\@deferlist\s@@deferlist
   \flushhere
\else
\typeout{float not placed here}%
\global\let\@deferlist\s@deferlist
\fi
    \else
\typeout{not h}%
    \global\let\@deferlist\s@deferlist
    \fi
   }%
  {%
\typeout{no pending float}%
}\par}}

\makeatother
\begin{document} 

"When entering the door at Lou's, two things are immediately noticeable: the place is rarely empty and seems to consist of a maze of rooms. The first room, through the door, is the main part of the restaurant. There is another, rarely used, dining room off to the right. It was added during the oil well boom of the seventies. Through the main dining room is yet another room; it guards the door leading into the kitchen. This room contains the most coveted table in the place. The highest tribute Lou can bestow on anyone is to allow them access to seats at this table. This table is the family table; it is reserved for Lou's, and her daughter Karen's, immediate family and treasured friends."

"Like his twisted feathers, his many scars, the reliable old owl chose the gnarled, weather-beaten, but solid branch often - it being a companion to the wise alone with the night and the last branch to creak in the heaviest wind. He often came to survey the fields and the clouds before his hunt, to listen to the steady sound of the stream passing through reeds under the bridge, while combing his feathers for the unwanteds - whatever they might be."

"Looking back on a childhood filled with events and memories, I find it rather difficult to pick one that leaves me with the fabled "warm and fuzzy feelings." As the daughter of an Air Force major, I had the pleasure of traveling across America in many moving trips. I have visited the monstrous trees of the Sequoia National Forest, stood on the edge of the Grand Canyon and have jumped on the beds at Caesar's Palace in Lake Tahoe."

"Looking back on a childhood filled with events and memories, I find it rather difficult to pick one that leaves me with the fabled "warm and fuzzy feelings." As the daughter of an Air Force major, I had the pleasure of traveling across America in many moving trips. I have visited the monstrous trees of the Sequoia National Forest, stood on the edge of the Grand Canyon and have jumped on the beds at Caesar's Palace in Lake Tahoe.r Force major, I  r Force major, I  r Force mmajor, I "

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering\rule{2cm}{1cm}
\par
\caption{ff}
\end{figure}

\flushhere

"Looking back on a childhood filled with events and memories, I find it rather difficult to pick one that leaves me with the fabled "warm and fuzzy feelings." As the daughter of an Air Force major, I had the pleasure of traveling across America in many moving trips. I have visited the monstrous trees of the Sequoia National Forest, stood on the edge of the Grand Canyon and have jumped on the beds at Caesar's Palace in Lake Tahoe."

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering\rule{2cm}{1cm}
\par
\caption{ff}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[hp]
\centering
\par
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{cc}1&2\\33&44\\555&666
\end{tabular}
\caption{tt}
\end{table}

"The day I picked my dog up from the pound was one of the happiest days of both of our lives. I had gone to the pound just a week earlier with the idea that I would just "look" at a puppy. Of course, you can no more just look at those squiggling little faces so filled with hope and joy than you can stop the sun from setting in the evening. I knew within minutes of walking in the door that I would get a puppy… but it wasn't until I saw him that I knew I had found my puppy."

"Looking for houses was supposed to be a fun and exciting process. Unfortunately, none of the ones that we saw seemed to match the specifications that we had established. They were too small, too impersonal, too close to the neighbors. After days of finding nothing even close, we began to wonder: was there really a perfect house out there for us?"

Below is a pdf link to personal statements and application essays representing strong efforts by students applying for both undergraduate and graduate opportunities. These ten essays have one thing in common: They were all written by students under the constraint of the essay being 1-2 pages due to the target program’s explicit instructions. In such circumstances, writers must attend carefully to the essay prompt (sometimes as simple as “Write a one-page summary of your reasons for wanting to pursue graduate study”) and recognize that evaluators tend to judge these essays on the same fundamental principles, as follows:

\begin{center}
% \begin{table}[htp!]
% \centering
\begin{tabular}{%
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=3.2,,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Descriptive Analysis 1}}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
& \textbf{MM}
& \textbf{CM} \\
\midrule
N       & {10}  &  {10}      \\
    Mean    & 91.45\%  & 8.55\% \\
    Median  & 94.74\%  & 5.26\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{the wantet title of table} % <========================
\label{tab:title123} % <===================================================
% \end{table}
\end{center}

"Billy Ray's Pawn Shop and Lawn Mower Repair looked like a burial ground for country auction rejects. The blazing, red, diesel fuel tanks beamed in front of the station, looking like cheap lipstick against the pallid, wrinkled texture of the parking lot sand. The yard, not much larger than the end zone at General G. Patton High School on the north end of town, was framed with a rusted metallic hedge of lawn mowers, banana seat bicycles, and corroded oil drums. It wasn't a calico frame of rusted parts, but rather an orchestra of unwanted machinery that Billy Ray had arranged into sections. The yellow-tanked mowers rested silently at the right of the diesel fuel. Once red, now faded orange, mowers stood at attention to the left. The oil barrels, jaded and pierced with holes, bellared like chimes when the wind was right. The bikes rested sporadically throughout the lot. In the middle of it all was the office, a faded, steel roof supported by cheap two-by-fours and zebra paneling. Billy Ray was at home, usually, five blocks east of town on Kennel Road."

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{%
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=3.2,,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Descriptive Analysis 1}}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
& \textbf{MM}
& \textbf{CM} \\
\midrule
N       & {10}  &  {10}      \\
    Mean    & 91.45\%  & 8.55\% \\
    Median  & 94.74\%  & 5.26\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{figure}{the wantet title of table} % <========================
\label{tab:title} % <===================================================
\end{center}



"When entering the door at Lou's, two things are immediately noticeable: the place is rarely empty and seems to consist of a maze of rooms. The first room, through the door, is the main part of the restaurant. There is another, rarely used, dining room off to the right. It was added during the oil well boom of the seventies. Through the main dining room is yet another room; it guards the door leading into the kitchen. This room contains the most coveted table in the place. The highest tribute Lou can bestow on anyone is to allow them access to seats at this table. This table is the family table; it is reserved for Lou's, and her daughter Karen's, immediate family and treasured friends.

\end{document}
```

Edited:
I added in more text and the first figure go the end of the document

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

 \usepackage{showframe}
 \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
 \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{makecell,siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{parskip} % <================================================
\usepackage{caption} % <================================================
\setcounter{totalnumber}{30}% lots of here floats

\makeatletter
\def\flushhere{\par{%
 \let\s@deferlist\@deferlist
 \let\@currbox\relax
\@next\@currbox\@deferlist{%
  \ifodd\count\@currbox
\typeout{Trying \meaning\@currbox (\number\@currbox/\the\count\@currbox),
        adding to \meaning\@currlist}%
    \@cons\@currlist\@currbox
\typeout{added: to \meaning\@currlist}%
\typeout{deferlist was \s@deferlist, now \@deferlist}%
\let\s@@deferlist\@deferlist\@empty
\global\let\@deferlist\@empty
    \@floatpenalty -\@Miii
      \penalty -\@Miv
      \@tempdima\prevdepth
      \vbox{}%
      \prevdepth\@tempdima
      \penalty\@floatpenalty
       \@@par
   \ifx\@deferlist\@empty
\typeout{float placed here}%
\global\let\@deferlist\s@@deferlist
   \flushhere
\else
\typeout{float not placed here}%
\global\let\@deferlist\s@deferlist
\fi
    \else
\typeout{not h}%
    \global\let\@deferlist\s@deferlist
    \fi
   }%
  {%
\typeout{no pending float}%
}\par}}

\makeatother
\begin{document} 

"When entering the door at Lou's, two things are immediately noticeable: the place is rarely empty and seems to consist of a maze of rooms. The first room, through the door, is the main part of the restaurant. There is another, rarely used, dining room off to the right. It was added during the oil well boom of the seventies. Through the main dining room is yet another room; it guards the door leading into the kitchen. This room contains the most coveted table in the place. The highest tribute Lou can bestow on anyone is to allow them access to seats at this table. This table is the family table; it is reserved for Lou's, and her daughter Karen's, immediate family and treasured friends."

"Like his twisted feathers, his many scars, the reliable old owl chose the gnarled, weather-beaten, but solid branch often - it being a companion to the wise alone with the night and the last branch to creak in the heaviest wind. He often came to survey the fields and the clouds before his hunt, to listen to the steady sound of the stream passing through reeds under the bridge, while combing his feathers for the unwanteds - whatever they might be."

"Looking back on a childhood filled with events and memories, I find it rather difficult to pick one that leaves me with the fabled "warm and fuzzy feelings." As the daughter of an Air Force major, I had the pleasure of traveling across America in many moving trips. I have visited the monstrous trees of the Sequoia National Forest, stood on the edge of the Grand Canyon and have jumped on the beds at Caesar's Palace in Lake Tahoe."

"Looking back on a childhood filled with events and memories, I find it rather difficult to pick one that leaves me with the fabled "warm and fuzzy feelings." As the daughter of an Air Force major, I had the pleasure of traveling across America in many moving trips. I have visited the monstrous trees of the Sequoia National Forest, stood on the edge of the Grand Canyon and have jumped on the beds at Caesar's Palace in Lake Tahoe.r Force major, I  r Force major, I  r Force mmajor, I d fuzzy feelings." As the daud fuzzy feelings." As the daud fuzzy feelings." As the dad fuzzy feelings." As the daud fuzzy feelings."

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering\rule{2cm}{1cm}
\par
\caption{ff}
\end{figure}

\flushhere

"Looking back on a childhood filled with events and memories, I find it rather difficult to pick one that leaves me with the fabled "warm and fuzzy feelings." As the daughter of an Air Force major, I had the pleasure of traveling across America in many moving trips. I have visited the monstrous trees of the Sequoia National Forest, stood on the edge of the Grand Canyon and have jumped on the beds at Caesar's Palace in Lake Tahoe."

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering\rule{2cm}{1cm}
\par
\caption{ff}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[hp]
\centering
\par
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{cc}1&2\\33&44\\555&666
\end{tabular}
\caption{tt}
\end{table}

"The day I picked my dog up from the pound was one of the happiest days of both of our lives. I had gone to the pound just a week earlier with the idea that I would just "look" at a puppy. Of course, you can no more just look at those squiggling little faces so filled with hope and joy than you can stop the sun from setting in the evening. I knew within minutes of walking in the door that I would get a puppy… but it wasn't until I saw him that I knew I had found my puppy."

"Looking for houses was supposed to be a fun and exciting process. Unfortunately, none of the ones that we saw seemed to match the specifications that we had established. They were too small, too impersonal, too close to the neighbors. After days of finding nothing even close, we began to wonder: was there really a perfect house out there for us?"

Below is a pdf link to personal statements and application essays representing strong efforts by students applying for both undergraduate and graduate opportunities. These ten essays have one thing in common: They were all written by students under the constraint of the essay being 1-2 pages due to the target program’s explicit instructions. In such circumstances, writers must attend carefully to the essay prompt (sometimes as simple as “Write a one-page summary of your reasons for wanting to pursue graduate study”) and recognize that evaluators tend to judge these essays on the same fundamental principles, as follows:

\begin{center}
% \begin{table}[htp!]
% \centering
\begin{tabular}{%
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=3.2,,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Descriptive Analysis 1}}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
& \textbf{MM}
& \textbf{CM} \\
\midrule
N       & {10}  &  {10}      \\
    Mean    & 91.45\%  & 8.55\% \\
    Median  & 94.74\%  & 5.26\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{the wantet title of table} % <========================
\label{tab:title123} % <===================================================
% \end{table}
\end{center}

"Billy Ray's Pawn Shop and Lawn Mower Repair looked like a burial ground for country auction rejects. The blazing, red, diesel fuel tanks beamed in front of the station, looking like cheap lipstick against the pallid, wrinkled texture of the parking lot sand. The yard, not much larger than the end zone at General G. Patton High School on the north end of town, was framed with a rusted metallic hedge of lawn mowers, banana seat bicycles, and corroded oil drums. It wasn't a calico frame of rusted parts, but rather an orchestra of unwanted machinery that Billy Ray had arranged into sections. The yellow-tanked mowers rested silently at the right of the diesel fuel. Once red, now faded orange, mowers stood at attention to the left. The oil barrels, jaded and pierced with holes, bellared like chimes when the wind was right. The bikes rested sporadically throughout the lot. In the middle of it all was the office, a faded, steel roof supported by cheap two-by-fours and zebra paneling. Billy Ray was at home, usually, five blocks east of town on Kennel Road."

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{%
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=3.2,,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Descriptive Analysis 1}}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
& \textbf{MM}
& \textbf{CM} \\
\midrule
N       & {10}  &  {10}      \\
    Mean    & 91.45\%  & 8.55\% \\
    Median  & 94.74\%  & 5.26\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{figure}{the wantet title of table} % <========================
\label{tab:title} % <===================================================
\end{center}



"When entering the door at Lou's, two things are immediately noticeable: the place is rarely empty and seems to consist of a maze of rooms. The first room, through the door, is the main part of the restaurant. There is another, rarely used, dining room off to the right. It was added during the oil well boom of the seventies. Through the main dining room is yet another room; it guards the door leading into the kitchen. This room contains the most coveted table in the place. The highest tribute Lou can bestow on anyone is to allow them access to seats at this table. This table is the family table; it is reserved for Lou's, and her daughter Karen's, immediate family and treasured friends.

\end{document}
```

Comment: For question 1:  *a*) the caption is above the table because `\caption` in your code is placed before the the `tabular`environment; *b*) anyway the typographical usages places the caption of a table *above* the table for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Bernard, thanks. `\begin{table}[hp]
\centering
\par
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{cc}1&2\\33&44\\555&666
\end{tabular}
\caption{tt}
\end{table}`. It works. I edit and cancel this question as it is simple questions

Comment: looking at your output, no figure is inserted mid-paragraph, so what is your question, what do you want to change?

Comment: as the code warns `no pending float`  `\flushhere` is doing nothing at all in this document and you get identical output if you do not use it. I do not think you want it at all, just use `\begin{figure}[hp]` floats.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry. I edited my questions again. I very confused with all these.

Comment: @aan you are making it far more complicated than it need be, 99.9% of latex documents use figures without using highly experimental code like this that is patching the float placement algorithm.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. the best way is `\begin{figure}[hp]` i guess?

Comment: @aan it is not clear why you want to prevent top floats (which are the standard solution to the  positioning of figures) but if you do not want top floats then `[hp]`  is all you have.

Comment: @aan The best is not to use any optional placement at all. See if LaTeX place the float correctly. If not, finish all writing and proofread the document twice.In the third proofreading pass, you can start looking at where the floats are placed, and start to tweak the placement. However, read Frank Mittelback's article [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111mitt-float.pdf).

Comment: @aan Also, Mittelbachs' article [Managing forlorn paragraph lines (a.k.a. widows and orphans) in LaTeX](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-3/tb123mitt-widows.pdf) is recommended reading before you start. All the work you are doing now, will probably be wasted time when you later edit the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no room to place the float "here" on the first page so if you don't want to allow top floats (which would be the normal solution) then you can place `\flushfloat` between later paragraphs, producing

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

 \usepackage{showframe}
 \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
 \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{makecell,siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{parskip} % <================================================
\usepackage{caption} % <================================================
\setcounter{totalnumber}{30}% lots of here floats

\makeatletter
\def\flushhere{\par{%
 \let\s@deferlist\@deferlist
 \let\@currbox\relax
\@next\@currbox\@deferlist{%
  \ifodd\count\@currbox
\typeout{Trying \meaning\@currbox (\number\@currbox/\the\count\@currbox),
        adding to \meaning\@currlist}%
    \@cons\@currlist\@currbox
\typeout{added: to \meaning\@currlist}%
\typeout{deferlist was \s@deferlist, now \@deferlist}%
\let\s@@deferlist\@deferlist\@empty
\global\let\@deferlist\@empty
    \@floatpenalty -\@Miii
      \penalty -\@Miv
      \@tempdima\prevdepth
      \vbox{}%
      \prevdepth\@tempdima
      \penalty\@floatpenalty
       \@@par
   \ifx\@deferlist\@empty
\typeout{float placed here}%
\global\let\@deferlist\s@@deferlist
   \flushhere
\else
\typeout{float not placed here}%
\global\let\@deferlist\s@deferlist
\fi
    \else
\typeout{not h}%
    \global\let\@deferlist\s@deferlist
    \fi
   }%
  {%
\typeout{no pending float}%
}\par}}

\makeatother
\begin{document} 

"When entering the door at Lou's, two things are immediately noticeable: the place is rarely empty and seems to consist of a maze of rooms. The first room, through the door, is the main part of the restaurant. There is another, rarely used, dining room off to the right. It was added during the oil well boom of the seventies. Through the main dining room is yet another room; it guards the door leading into the kitchen. This room contains the most coveted table in the place. The highest tribute Lou can bestow on anyone is to allow them access to seats at this table. This table is the family table; it is reserved for Lou's, and her daughter Karen's, immediate family and treasured friends."

"Like his twisted feathers, his many scars, the reliable old owl chose the gnarled, weather-beaten, but solid branch often - it being a companion to the wise alone with the night and the last branch to creak in the heaviest wind. He often came to survey the fields and the clouds before his hunt, to listen to the steady sound of the stream passing through reeds under the bridge, while combing his feathers for the unwanteds - whatever they might be."

"Looking back on a childhood filled with events and memories, I find it rather difficult to pick one that leaves me with the fabled "warm and fuzzy feelings." As the daughter of an Air Force major, I had the pleasure of traveling across America in many moving trips. I have visited the monstrous trees of the Sequoia National Forest, stood on the edge of the Grand Canyon and have jumped on the beds at Caesar's Palace in Lake Tahoe."

"Looking back on a childhood filled with events and memories, I find it rather difficult to pick one that leaves me with the fabled "warm and fuzzy feelings." As the daughter of an Air Force major, I had the pleasure of traveling across America in many moving trips. I have visited the monstrous trees of the Sequoia National Forest, stood on the edge of the Grand Canyon and have jumped on the beds at Caesar's Palace in Lake Tahoe.r Force major, I  r Force major, I  r Force mmajor, I d fuzzy feelings." As the daud fuzzy feelings." As the daud fuzzy feelings." As the dad fuzzy feelings." As the daud fuzzy feelings."

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering\rule{2cm}{1cm}
\par
\caption{ff}
\end{figure}

\flushhere

"Looking back on a childhood filled with events and memories, I find it rather difficult to pick one that leaves me with the fabled "warm and fuzzy feelings." As the daughter of an Air Force major, I had the pleasure of traveling across America in many moving trips. I have visited the monstrous trees of the Sequoia National Forest, stood on the edge of the Grand Canyon and have jumped on the beds at Caesar's Palace in Lake Tahoe."

\flushhere

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering\rule{2cm}{1cm}
\par
\caption{ff}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[hp]
\centering
\par
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{cc}1&2\\33&44\\555&666
\end{tabular}
\caption{tt}
\end{table}

"The day I picked my dog up from the pound was one of the happiest days of both of our lives. I had gone to the pound just a week earlier with the idea that I would just "look" at a puppy. Of course, you can no more just look at those squiggling little faces so filled with hope and joy than you can stop the sun from setting in the evening. I knew within minutes of walking in the door that I would get a puppy… but it wasn't until I saw him that I knew I had found my puppy."

"Looking for houses was supposed to be a fun and exciting process. Unfortunately, none of the ones that we saw seemed to match the specifications that we had established. They were too small, too impersonal, too close to the neighbors. After days of finding nothing even close, we began to wonder: was there really a perfect house out there for us?"

Below is a pdf link to personal statements and application essays representing strong efforts by students applying for both undergraduate and graduate opportunities. These ten essays have one thing in common: They were all written by students under the constraint of the essay being 1-2 pages due to the target program’s explicit instructions. In such circumstances, writers must attend carefully to the essay prompt (sometimes as simple as “Write a one-page summary of your reasons for wanting to pursue graduate study”) and recognize that evaluators tend to judge these essays on the same fundamental principles, as follows:

\begin{center}
% \begin{table}[htp!]
% \centering
\begin{tabular}{%
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=3.2,,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Descriptive Analysis 1}}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
& \textbf{MM}
& \textbf{CM} \\
\midrule
N       & {10}  &  {10}      \\
    Mean    & 91.45\%  & 8.55\% \\
    Median  & 94.74\%  & 5.26\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{the wantet title of table} % <========================
\label{tab:title123} % <===================================================
% \end{table}
\end{center}

"Billy Ray's Pawn Shop and Lawn Mower Repair looked like a burial ground for country auction rejects. The blazing, red, diesel fuel tanks beamed in front of the station, looking like cheap lipstick against the pallid, wrinkled texture of the parking lot sand. The yard, not much larger than the end zone at General G. Patton High School on the north end of town, was framed with a rusted metallic hedge of lawn mowers, banana seat bicycles, and corroded oil drums. It wasn't a calico frame of rusted parts, but rather an orchestra of unwanted machinery that Billy Ray had arranged into sections. The yellow-tanked mowers rested silently at the right of the diesel fuel. Once red, now faded orange, mowers stood at attention to the left. The oil barrels, jaded and pierced with holes, bellared like chimes when the wind was right. The bikes rested sporadically throughout the lot. In the middle of it all was the office, a faded, steel roof supported by cheap two-by-fours and zebra paneling. Billy Ray was at home, usually, five blocks east of town on Kennel Road."

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{%
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=3.2,,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Descriptive Analysis 1}}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
& \textbf{MM}
& \textbf{CM} \\
\midrule
N       & {10}  &  {10}      \\
    Mean    & 91.45\%  & 8.55\% \\
    Median  & 94.74\%  & 5.26\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{figure}{the wantet title of table} % <========================
\label{tab:title} % <===================================================
\end{center}



"When entering the door at Lou's, two things are immediately noticeable: the place is rarely empty and seems to consist of a maze of rooms. The first room, through the door, is the main part of the restaurant. There is another, rarely used, dining room off to the right. It was added during the oil well boom of the seventies. Through the main dining room is yet another room; it guards the door leading into the kitchen. This room contains the most coveted table in the place. The highest tribute Lou can bestow on anyone is to allow them access to seats at this table. This table is the family table; it is reserved for Lou's, and her daughter Karen's, immediate family and treasured friends.

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. I tried to implement in my thesis. Basically, use `\begin{figure}[hp]` and add in `\flushhere` in-between paragraph that the figure/table does not appear in a correct position. I am so confused after editing my part.

Comment: @aan the correct (normal) position is at the top of a later page, not between paragraphs, also it is best not to worry at all about the float placement until the document is finished, as they will move as the text is edited.

Comment: thanks. Yes, when I applied in my thesis, a bit mess, very headache. What is the best advice from you for writing a thesis, use `[hp] for all the figure and table and add `\flushhere` in-between paragraph that the figure/table does not appear in a correct position. Am I correct?

Comment: @aan no my advice is as above, not to use this at all and let latex position floats in the usual way. Readers expect floats to be at the top of the page (or bottom) if they are moved, not re-inserted between paragraphs.