# How can I let floats interrupt my text, but only at paragraph-resolution?

Tags: floats, line-breaking, paragraphs, placeins

I'm writing some text, with a float at some point. I don't mind where my float is placed exactly, but - I do mind if it breaks up individual paragraphs into two pieces, before and after the float`.`

I just read this:

[How to protect text from being split by a float?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25917/how-to-protect-text-from-being-split-by-a-float)

where the (single and accepted) answer suggests some measure of clearing floats, or postponing the presentation of any floats (using `placeins` or `flafter`). But - that's not what I want; I'm ok with floats either appearing or not-appearing after or earlier than this point - I just want paragraphs to remain intact. What should I use instead?

Comment: put samepage around every paragraph to prevent that they get split over pages.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246155/how-to-place-floats-between-paragraphs/246315#246315

Comment: You really have to disable the entire float mechanism, see the answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507528/using-flushhere-for-table-figure-position#comment1282529_507532

Comment: You could ignore the float system and use something based on `\everypar`.  The tricky bit would be near the bottom of the page.  It might be easier just to place everyhing by hand, possibly using `\raggedbottom` for the occasional gaps.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Where would I put `\raggedbottom`? Also, manual placemene of figure content may give me trouble with lists-of-figures and such.

Comment: Use the [H] option (float package) for manual placement.  `\raggedbottom` could go in the preamble, or possibly `\AtBeginDocumant`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo at paragraph breaks (so `\everypar`) you can get reliable `\pagegoal` and `\pagetotal` values to check whether your current float fits. Then you'd have different options for the placement (greedy vs not more than *n* floats; prefer top/bottom of page over midpage; etc.)

Comment: @Skillmon - I was thinking one float between paragraphs until `\@deferlist` is empty of [p] floats.